# setting Ext.data.proxy.Server:api property inline

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, extjs5, sencha-architect

Ext store proxy api object can be assigned from the definition. But I wanted to append a base-url to the api-request-links. I know this can be done from the controllers or via the init functionalities of the store. But it seemed quite a workaround to me.

I was trying to create a "getBaseUrl()" function in the application scope and expected it to be used throughout the application where ever there is a url or api store property defined something cleaner like this

```
...
...
store:{
myStore:{
...
proxy:{
    ...
    api{
    read: ApplicationName.getBaseUrl()+"the/rest/of/the/read-url",
    ...
    }
    ...
...
```

But I was unable to get the application context or controller context within the Ext.data.proxy.Server:api object. Can you help me out with a cleaner approach, instead of defining the store and applying the api from the controllers or assigning the proxy-api from the init of the store.

Comment: You can add `getBaseUrl` function in the app.js file and can access it using `ApplicationName.app.getBaseUrl()`.

Comment: actually that solution won't work. But I was able to access the getBaseUrl() function from a static context within a utility class eg:

Ext.define('AppName.utilities.Utils', {
    alternateClassName: 'Utils.Constants',
    statics: {
        getBaseUrl:function(){
            return "Base_Url";
        }
    },
});

But I had to add the utils class in the app folder and add it to the views[] array in the application js file for getting this done. I was not able to define a static utility directly within the application js file via architect though.